# Replace a character in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string like this `Config ID :AB12` in a file. 
I need to replace this into 
`{"Config ID" :"AB12"}` using java script. Any clue? Thanks.

Note: AB12 might be anything with 4-5 alphanumberic characters.

Comment: You need to create an object out of it as well? Your question title says something different.

Comment: Split the string by ":", trim the values, put them as key-value into an object, JSON-encode it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be solve using `split`

```js
var str = 'Config ID :AB12';

var arr = {};

arr[str.split(':')[0]] = str.split(':')[1];
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that's what you want:

```
yourStr.replace(/Config ID :([A-Za-z0-9]{4,5})/g, '{"Config ID" :"$1"}')
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var my_string = "Config ID :AB12";
var y = {};
y[my_string.split(':')[0]] = my_string.split(':')[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with regex

```
var string1 = 'Code ID: 12212, Code ID: 43433';
var re = new RegExp(/\Code ID: (\d{4}\d?)/g);
var result = string1.replace(re, '{"Code Id" : "$1"}');
console.log(result); //"{"Code Id" : "12212"}, {"Code Id" : "43433"}"
```

Comment: Can you do this without hard coding the key `Code Id`?

Comment: then it would replace all occurrences of a 4,5 digit number in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Computed Property Names](http://es6-features.org/#ComputedPropertyNames) (ES6)

```js
var id = "Config ID :AB12".split(':'),

id = { 
  [id[0]]: id[1] 
}


console.log(id)
```